# Does the Conservative Movement uphold restrictions on marriage for Kohanim?

Tags: halacha, marriage, kohen-priest, conservative-judaism

Does the Conservative Movement restrict kohanim from marrying divorcées and converts according to *halakha*?

I have never heard of this coming up for Conservative Jews and most Conservative Jews that I know have never heard of this *halakha*, which implies that it's not enforced (though I don't know any Conservative *kohanim* well, so maybe the people I know don't know about this *halakha* because it's not relevant to them).

If the Conservative Movement does not enforce this *halakha*, why not?

Comment: IINM they argue that our Kohanim are only Safek Kohanim and that it's better to allow this than risk them marrying gentiles.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting. Will be curious to see if that is addressed in the now nearly inevitable event that intermarriage becomes permitted in Conservative circles.

Comment: Here are the sources http://oldschedu.com/AskTheRabbi.aspx?ID=271

Comment: Their chumash, the the *Ḥumash Etz Ḥayim*, has a note that children of such relationships are challalim, but that Kohanim need only renounce the rights and responsibilities associated with their kehunah while married to women who are forbidden (see commentary on Emor)